# Why can't I upgrade zsh?

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, unattended-upgrades

Working on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. `zsh` is a package, for which an upgrade is available:

```
# apt-cache policy zsh
zsh:
  Installed: 5.0.2-3ubuntu6
  Candidate: 5.0.2-3ubuntu6
  Version table:
     5.0.5-4ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.0.2-3ubuntu6 0
        500 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

However, neither `apt-get install zsh` nor `unattended-upgrades` would upgrade it:

### apt-get

```
# apt-get install --dry-run zsh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
zsh is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

### unattended-upgrade

```
# unattended-upgrade --debug   
Initial blacklisted packages: 
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: ['o=LP-PPA-brightbox-ruby-ng,a=trusty', 'o=Percona Development Team,a=', 'o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security', 'o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates', 'o=Ubuntu,a=trusty', 'o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports', 'o=LP-PPA-ondrej-php,a=trusty', 'o=RabbitMQ,a=testing', 'o=LP-PPA-vbernat-haproxy-1.5,a=trusty', 'o=Node Source,a=', 'o=,a=now', 'o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security', 'o=Ubuntu,a=trusty', 'o=UbuntuESM,a=trusty', 'o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates', 'o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-proposed', 'o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports', 'o=LP-PPA-ondrej-php,a=trusty', 'o=LP-PPA-brightbox-ruby-ng,a=trusty', 'o=Node Source,a=trusty']
pkgs that look like they should be upgraded: 
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                         
fetch.run() result: 0
blacklist: []
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

Even if I explicitly request the new version, no upgrade will take place:

```
# apt-get install zsh=5.0.5-4ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  zsh
Suggested packages:
  zsh-doc
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Why would `apt-get` lie to me, that I already have the latest version? Why would `unattended-upgrades` similarly skip it, even though I list all possible origins, including `trusty-backports`, in its `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` as "allowed"?

*UPDATE*: yes, it would make sense, that "backports" be disabled by default. However, we have them listed as valid origins in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Even if I remove the `restricted` part from the above lines, it still would not upgrade zsh...

*UPDATE*: After studying the [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) @olivierb2 offered in his comment below, I created `/etc/apt/preferences.d/equalize` to force equal priority to all origins:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=trusty-security
Pin-Priority: 509

Package: *
Pin: release a=trusty
Pin-Priority: 509

Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 509

Package: *
Pin: release a=trusty-updates
Pin-Priority: 509

Package: *
Pin: release a=trusty-backports
Pin-Priority: 509

Package: *
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 509
```

And now things work as I expect them to:

```
# apt-cache policy zsh
zsh:
  Installed: 5.0.2-3ubuntu6
  Candidate: 5.0.5-4ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
     5.0.5-4ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        509 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.0.2-3ubuntu6 0
        509 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        509 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I still do not understand, just what controls the priorities in the absence of explicit "preferences" setting. But now I have the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backports are disabled by default, you have to use the following command to upgrade your package from backports

```
apt-get install zsh -t trusty-backports
```

Edit: I miss the [source page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) where you can find information

Comment: Is it written in some config-file, that backports are disabled, or is it hard-coded in `apt-get` and `unattended-upgrades` somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: I updated my question with additional details. Would you give it another glance, please?

Comment: Apt rules regarding Backports is hard coded. It's not very recommended to bypass this rules. More information here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

Comment: I still can't find, _where_ it is hardcoded. The command `dpkg -L apt | xargs fgrep -d skip backports` does not list anything... But your link identified, how to work-around this -- I when I pinning priorities, one must use `release` instead of `origin` I used above! Thanks.

Comment: E: The value 'trusty-backports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources